# usage of hugepages for text and data segments

Tags: c, linux-kernel, elf, huge-pages

I am exploring the possibility to back the text and data segment with hugepages following the guide in https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO.

I have relinked the application as suggested by adding "-B/usr/share/libhugetlbfs -Wl,--hugetlbfs-align" and started the application with "hugectl --text --data --heap --bss /path/to/my/application".

But I am not very sure how to verify whether the data and text segments are indeed copied to the files on the hugetlbfs filesystem.

Checking the /proc/{pid}/maps, it could be seen that the hugepages are used for heap but not for text and data segments as the first two address ranges are mapped to the application but not the hugepage file system.

Is my understanding correct? Actually I suspect my conclusion that hugepages are used for heap from /proc/{pid}/maps is also incorrect.

How should I verify whether the data and text segments are backed in the hugepages? I know that data and text segments will be copied to hugetlbfs filesystem if successful but how to verify it?

Thanks!

output of /proc/{pid}/maps

```
00400000-00d2c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 46153351 /path/to/my/application

00f2b000-00fa3000 rw-p 0092b000 fd:02 46153351 /path/to/my/application

00fa3000-00fbb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

02a0c000-02a2d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  [heap]

40000000-80000000 rw-p 00000000 00:15 2476090 /dev/hugepages-1G/libhugetlbfs.tmp.nS7exn (deleted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check

```
   /proc/$pid/numa_maps
```

contains information about each memory area used by a given process allowing--among other information--the determination of which nodes were used for the pages.

for formar see http://linux.die.net/man/5/numa_maps

Comment: See also /proc/$pid/smaps for detailed info about each mapping, including anonymous hugepages.   BSS is an anonymous mapping like the heap, and will use transparent hugemages for mappings that are sufficiently aligned.

Answer (score 1):

If you set HUGETLB_DEBUG=1 variable, it will tell you whole lot of useful information. One of them is this:

> INFO: Segment 2's aligned memsz is too small: 0x864 < 0xffffffffffffffff

If it is successful it looks like:

> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: INFO: Segment 0 (phdr 2): 0x400000-0x400864  (filesz=0x864) (prot = 0x5)
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: INFO: Segment 1 (phdr 3): 0x600868-0x600af8  (filesz=0x27c) (prot = 0x3)
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: DEBUG: Total memsz = 0xaf4, memsz of largest segment = 0x864
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: INFO: libhugetlbfs version: 2.16 (modified)
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154951]: INFO: Mapped hugeseg at 0x2aaaaac00000. Copying 0x864 bytes and 0 extra bytes from 0x400000...done
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: INFO: Prepare succeeded
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154952]: INFO: Mapped hugeseg at 0x2aaaaac00000. Copying 0x27c bytes and 0 extra bytes from 0x600868...done
>
> libhugetlbfs [zupa:154297]: INFO: Prepare succeeded

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get text sections backed by huge pages on current linux kernels is to compile it with the experimental `CONFIG_READ_ONLY_THP_FOR_FS=y` option and setting the THP policy to `always`.

Some distros ship kernels with that set, you can check with `zgrep THP_FOR_FS /proc/config.gz`